# Split JSON into two arrays gives undefined keys-values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, chart.js

I have a project to do that I create a json object from a database and then I need to get it with the help of ajax and split it into two arrays so I can use the values to create a chart on chart.js.I can get the json object but the problem is that when i try to loop through it to create my two arrays I get undefined values instead of the values that the json contains...It maybe be something really stupid but I still learning so I cant figure it out.I already tried many of the answers that were given in other similar cases but nothing worked.

When I try to run my data.php that creates the json I get this on my browser:

```
[{"name":"Messenger","number":"29"},{"name":"Viber","number":"28"},{"name":"Facebook","number":"28"},{"name":"Skype","number":"17"}]
```

My javascript to get the json,split it into two arrays and create the chart:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/project_test/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            //trying to create the two arrays...
            var applications = [];
            var number = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                applications.push("App name " + data[i]['name']);
                number.push(data[i].number);
            }
            console.log(applications);
            console.log(number);

            //chart.js things....
            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: applications,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Chart',
                        data: number,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },  
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }               
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I used both ways ( `data[i].name` and `data[i]['name']` ) to get the values but none of them worked.

[my console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siqrH.png)

Comment: You have to add the option `dataType` as `json` or do the json deserialization your own first to use it.

Comment: shouldn't use `for in` loop on arrays

Comment: Your code for splitting into array is working fine for me with the data provided. Please check this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/ap4rsd7g/

Comment: the log on line 327 clearly shows that you still have a string, not an array of objects. I doubt you intended to loop over a string.

Comment: From your console logs, it is clear that the loop is iterating over 100 times, which makes sense if `data` is a string because it is iterating over each character in the string. Do what @Mario suggests, and your code will work. The ordering will not be reliable though. To fix that you should also do what @dburgener shows.

Comment: Well the problem was that i did not add the option dataType: 'json', as mario alexandro santini mentioned....when i added that option the script worked like a charm! Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score -1):

You are using a for in loop, instead of a for loop.

```
for(var i in data) {
            applications.push("App name " + data[i]['name']);
            number.push(data[i].number);
        }
```

should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            applications.push("App name " + data[i]['name']);
            number.push(data[i].number);
        }
```

Comment: this gives me exactly the same result like the for in

Answer (score -1):

You are getting an array of objects. With jQuery, you can approach the 2 arrays like this:

```
var data = [{"name":"Messenger","number":"29"},{"name":"Viber","number":"28"},{"name":"Facebook","number":"28"},{"name":"Skype","number":"17"}];

var names = [];
var numbers = [];

$.each(data, function(i, row) {
    names.push(row.name);
    numbers.push(row.number);
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h73stq8/)**

Comment: well this gives me an error...uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '131' in [{"name":"Messenger","number":"29"},{"name":"Viber","number":"28"},{"name":"Facebook","number":"28"},{"name":"Skype","number":"17"}]

Comment: The error is not linked to the code above. It's linked to your implementation. Don't use `for...in`, use the `$.each()` that jQuery provides. If that's not the problem, it lies somewhere else. Can't tell you where, without the code.